# How do you use style sheets in TeXworks?

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

How do you choose which .sty file a document uses in TeXworks?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to load a package?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand the problem; I misunderstood what a .sty file was. I didn't realize a .sty file was the same as a package. I had a standalone .sty file that I wanted to incorporate into my document. In order to do it I did the following (I am using TeXworks/MiKtex on Windows):

- Create a new directory "C:/Local Tex Files/tex/latex/misc" and put the file "myfile.sty" in there.
- Go into the MikTex settings and add "C:/Local Tex Files" as a root directory.
- Add "\usepackage{myfile}" to the document preamble.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows